# How to install Git on redhat RHEL 6.5

Tags: git, github, redhat, rhel, rhel6

I'm struggling to install the Git on my RHEL 6.5, first i tried 'yum install git' and give me no package found, then I try add those repo by using the rpm -Uvh command and none working.

After i found this link http://tecadmin.net/install-git-2-0-on-centos-rhel-fedora/# and try to follow, but getting nowhere , because I can't do the step1

install the yum install curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel

Keep saying no package found, nothing to do.

Very frustrated, why so difficult...

All I want to do is create a build server by install the GIT, NODE JS , GULP, BOWER, NPM and use Jenkins to auto build the project when new code committed to the git hub.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems yum repo is not configured on your machine. 
To verify please run command "yum repolist".

"yum update" or "yum upgrade" will help here to configure rhel default repo.
Then run "yum list | grep git" to check available git packages and install package as per your need.

Comment: Hi Thanks, after put yum list | grep git and see below, what does it means? how to install it? libpcap.x86_64                      14:1.4.0-4.20130826git2dbcaa1.el6
numad.x86_64                        0.5-12.20150602git.el6 @EDS-OPSW-repo.4Q2015
tcpdump.x86_64                      14:4.0.0-5.20090921gitdf3cb4.2.el6
xorg-x11-drv-xgi.x86_64             1.6.0-20.20121114git.el6
xorg-x11-glamor.x86_64              0.6.0-5.20140506gitf78901e.el6
xz.x86_64                           4.999.9-0.5.beta.20091007git.el6

Comment: repos are not configured, so you have to either enable them or install git manually.
to enable epel run : "sudo yum install epel-release". after configuring yum you may proceed with git installation with "yum install git"

To install git manually  refer below link:
http://tecadmin.net/install-git-1-9-on-centos-rhel/#